# How to sort an a list of currency values as integers?

Tags: python, sorting

I have an object with variables "price", "title", and "city". I want to order them by price:

```
itemlist.sort(key = lambda x: x._price)
for i in itemlist:
    print(i._price, i._title, i._city)
```

Assuming I have prices `["$1", "$3", "$22", "$12"]`. It sorts them `["$1", "$12", "$22", "$3"]` when I want it to be `["$1", "$3", "$12", "$22"]`.

I know it's because price is considered a string and not an int, but what I don't know is how to convert it into an int for the sake of sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly sort items in a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592499/how-to-properly-sort-items-in-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the elements of the list to an `int` by remove the `'$'`. One way is by using `str.strip()`:

```
itemlist.sort(key = lambda x: int(x._price.strip('$'))
```

Or if you're open to using regular expressions, you could filter out non-digits:

```
import re
itemlist.sort(key = lambda x: int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x._price)))
```

Where `[^0-9]` means match anything that is not a digit.

Comment: Altertively: `itemlist.sort(key = lambda x: int(x._price[1:]))`

Answer (score 1):

Naive fix that assumes all price strings start with `$`:

```
itemlist.sort(key=lambda x: float(x._price[1:]))
```

But it's probably a better idea to keep `$` out of your prices in the first place, and only add it in when you are printing the price.  Store the price as a `float` or as an `int`.  That will also allow you to do normal math with your prices that you couldn't easily do with strings.